# How to add elements to different <li>

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code where there is a question and many options.
I have an unordered list `ul` and I am trying to all in that list many `li` where each one will contain a option name and a checkbox.

My code for the moment add the `li` but it add the checkbox and the name under it and not in it.

It looks something like this.

```
<ul>
  <li class="optionName"></li>
  <label for="checkbox00">Option 0</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox00" />
  <li class="optionName"></li>
  <label for="checkbox01">Option 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox01" />
</ul>
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="optionName">
    <label for="checkbox00">Option 0</label> <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox00" />
  </li>
  <li class="optionName">
    <label for="checkbox01">Option 1</label> <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox01" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

My code where I am adding the html looks like this:

```js
var option = document.createElement('li');
var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
var label = document.createElement('label');
var checkBoxId = 'checkbox' + '' + questionNumber + subquestionNumber;
checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
checkbox.id = checkBoxId;
option.className = 'optionName';
label.htmlFor = checkBoxId;
checkBoxId.htmlFor = option;
label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Option ' + subquestionNumber));
q.appendChild(option);
q.appendChild(label);
q.appendChild(checkbox);
```

Comment: what you showed that you want is no valid HTML, you should place the labels and inputs in the content of the `<li>`, not in the tag. So `<li ...><label ...><input ...></li>`

Comment: Try `option.appendChild(label)` and `option.appendChild(checkbox)` instead of `q.appendChild(...)` and the append option to q like `q.appendChild(option)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `appendChild` on `option` instead of `q`

```
var option = document.createElement('li');
        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        var label = document.createElement('label')
        var checkBoxId = "checkbox" + "" + questionNumber + subquestionNumber;
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.id = checkBoxId;
        option.className = "optionName";
        label.htmlFor = checkBoxId;
        checkBoxId.htmlFor = option;
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Option ' + subquestionNumber));
        option.appendChild(label); //add `label` to `li`
        option.appendChild(checkbox); //add `checkbox` to `li`
        q.appendChild(option)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an aside you may find working with [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) easier to visualise.

I've created a function into which you can pass the `questionNumber` and `subquestionNumber` arguments. The function returns some HTML using those arguments.

If you then use `querySelector` to pick up the `ul` element, you can then use `insertAdjacentHTML` to add the result of calling the function to the list.

```js
function getHTML(questionNo, subQuestionNo) {

  const id = `${questionNo}${subQuestionNo}`;

  return html = `
    <li class="optionName">
      <label for="checkbox${id}">
        Option ${questionNo}.${subQuestionNo}
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox${id}">
    </li>
  `;

}

// Get the `ul` element
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');

// Add new HTML to the `ul` element by calling the
// `getHTML` function with the `questionNumber` and
// `subQuestionNumber` arguments.
ul.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', getHTML(0, 0));
ul.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', getHTML(0, 1));
ul.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', getHTML(1, 1));
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Additional documentation

- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)